# Modifications to QWizard and QWizardPage

Tags: qt

I was wondering if there was a way to modify the panel behind the buttons?  I need to change the color.  Also is there a way to remove the CANCEL button on the finish page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the cancel button is such a user experience no-no that you should really reconsider it. If you insist on doing potentially the wrong thing:

```
wizard->setOption(QWizard::NoCancelButton);
```

You can call it from a reimplementation of `QWizardPage::initializePage`, that way it will remove the button as the page is being shown.

You can use [the style sheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/stylesheet.html) to customize the look of your panel. You can also manually change its pallette.